# Reverse biased photodiode gain resistor selection

Tags: photodiode, rise-time

I have a reverse biased photodiode as shown below.

[image]

where  R1 = 100kΩ. The output is quite low around 50mV. I would like to replace R1 with 1MΩ to get 10x the output. My concern is, if it will have any disadvantage? Does it have any effect on the rise time?

Comment: It'll affect the fall time.

Comment: Could you explain a bit?

Comment: Could you add an opamp to the circuit?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it will slow down the response (assuming the load presented by your sense circuit is still "high" compared to 1 MΩ). As far as AC circuits go, the junction capacitance of the photodiode is in parallel with the resistor, forming a low pass filter.

Increasing the resistance may also increase the noise, as the Johnson noise of the resistor goes as

$$\bar{v_n^2} = 4 k_B T R$$

Comment: Isn't the junction capacitor in series with R1 here?

Comment: Not in terms of what signal gets to whatever's connected to the output. Remember that a power supply is an ac ground.